# How to move/reorder an html table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The idea is to move a particular table row to a different location
HTML

```
<table id="grid1" class="table table-zebra">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 1 tr 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 2 tr 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 3 tr 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 4 tr 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 5 tr 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 6 tr 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 6 tr 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 7 tr 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 8 tr 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 9 tr 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 10 tr 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cont 11 tr 11</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Cont 12 tr 12</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Cont 13 tr 13</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Cont 14 tr 14</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That is the basic table, now, how do I can I move the TR 11 in a away that it will be under TR 4, I'm sorry that I don't post any JS but I have no idea how to do it... I was looking at this [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/uroyi/195/edit?html,js,output) which is nice but can't use it..

Comment: Look at jQuery clone detach append. Can't answer thru my phone.

Comment: Based on what criteria will you move row 11 under the 4th row? Also, do you expect to click somewhere in order to move that row? Think in terms of the User first, what steps will he/she take to "move" the row?

Comment: No, there are no criteria in order to move that particular row, the table is always the same and the content is displayed in that order, I could move that manually but I have no access to the file that generates that html, only the output which is that, the user don't need to click anywhere, once the html is loaded that row need to be move to it;s correct location..

Comment: @LShetty clone and detach may not be appropriate. Tanker doesn't want to clone the element, just move it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the 11th tr to under the 4th:

```
 $("tbody tr:nth-child(11)").insertAfter("tbody tr:nth-child(4)");
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rnby90r5/)

If you prefer vanilla, you need the selectors the other way around.

```
document.querySelector("tbody tr:nth-child(4)").insertAdjacentElement("afterend", document.querySelector("tbody tr:nth-child(11)"));
```

Comment: Whats the vanilla answer though?

Comment: @Shawn `document.querySelector("tbody tr:nth-child(4)").insertAdjacentElement("afterend", document.querySelector("tbody tr:nth-child(11)"));`

Answer (score 4):

In the context of an HTML table with rows that look like this:

```
<tr class="form-grid-view-row">
    <td> 
        <a class="up" href="#">⇑</a>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <a class="down" href="#">⇓</a>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <span id="index1" class="form-label">1</span>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <span id="span1" class="form-label">Value 1</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this script:

```
$('.up,.down').click(function () {
    var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    if ($(this).is('.up')) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
});
```

> $('.up,.down').click(function () {

This is selecting every DOM element with the class "up" and every element with the class "down", e.g. `$('.up,.down').click(function () {`.  The function sets up a click handler for each element.

> var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');

`$(this)` refers to the DOM element which is the target of the click handler (one of the "up" or "down" elements which was selected above).  `.parents()` looks for `tr:first`, the first `<tr>` element starting with `<a>` and travelling up the DOM.  It'll end up selecting the entire row.

> if ($(this).is('.up')) {

This is checking to see whether or not the element selected has the class "up" or not.

> row.insertBefore(row.prev());

This takes the row that was clicked, and moves it right above the upper-most sibling of the row that was clicked.

The jQuery methods used (insertBefore, prev, is, parents, etc.) are described in greater detail in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using JQuery Library.

```
// selecting tbody is bad instead you need to give an id or class to this tag and select according to this

var fourth = $( "tbody tr:nth-child(4)" ),
    eleventh = $( "tbody tr:nth-child(11)" );
$( "tbody tr:nth-child(11)" ).insertAfter(fourth);
```

Comment: This will work but bear in mind if there are any elements that have events bound to them, this will remove that function. If that's important, you can move the elements around instead by using `.insertAfter()` and similar functions.

Comment: Actually this doesn't do what was asked. There was no request to move the 4th row

Comment: The use of VAR I like it, I can use it like `var fourth = $( "tbody tr:nth-child(4)" ),
    eleventh = $( "tbody tr:nth-child(11)" );
$(eleventh).insertAfter(fourth); eleventh.addClass('moved');`

Answer (score 1):

In order to move dynamically your elements you can add an event to all tbody children. What I basically do is select one element on first click then I move it after second element clicked.

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
    var $tbody = $("#grid");
    var selected = null;
    $tbody.children().on("click", function () {
       if (selected == null)
           selected = this;
       else
       {
           $(selected).insertAfter(this);
           selected = null;
       }
    });
});
```

It move after an element but is just an idea, you can customize it.
Your html should be like this.

```
<table>
    <tbody id="grid">
        <tr> <td> 1 </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> 2 </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> 3 </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> 4 </td> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```